# Converting MDX Queries to SQL equivalent

Tags: sql, mdx

I have a set of MDX queries used to build Cubes and the corresponding tables utilized. My reporting tool supports only RDBMS so i need to convert MDX to SQL. How can the be done

Answer (score 0):

That I know of there is no specific tool to simply convert from MDX to SQL so you will need to extract the logic and rewrite in SQL.